# Controller and routes - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller

i would know how i can insert all my controllers in routes without repeat use.... use...

example:

```
<?php use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
      use App\Http\Controllers\DB;
      use App\Http\Controllers\DB1;
      use App\Http\Controllers\DB2;
      use App\Http\Controllers\DB3;
      use App\Http\Controllers\DB4;
      use App\Http\Controllers\DB5;
      use App\Http\Controllers\DB6;
      etc.....
      Route::get('/', function () {
          return view('welcome');
      });
```

How can i insert a lot of controllers in only one time??
Thanks a lot.

P.S. DB1,DB2,etcc are example XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to work with **`web.php`**  and `routing` in laravel 8 the same as previous ones, which you don't need to import the controllers. you can do the following work:

1. to `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php` add `$namespace`

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
   // add this line
   protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
}
```

2. Second add the `$namespace` to `boot` method of `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot() {
   //...... other codes   

   //add the below code
   $this->routes(function() {
      Route::middlware('web')->namespace($this->namespace);
   });
}
```

Comment: I tried your solutions, but didn't work.
Secondo solutions it's my last resorce ahahah

Comment: Try to restart your project then re run it.

Comment: I receive Error 404 - Not found

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
use App\Http\Controllers\{DB, DB1, DB2, ...};
```

More reference [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.group)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try but i wouldn't write every controllers by hand ahahah.
There isn't a modality to call all the file in controllers folder?